# NameError bug python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Hello I have been learning python 3 for 2 days now, there is an exercise in the book learn python the hard about OOP. So basically when I run the engine for my game it pull up a

**

```
"current_scene.enter()
NameError: name 'current_scene' is not defined"
```

**

Please is there something I'm missing ?

[PasteBin code](https://pastebin.com/dY5nTWh7)

```
class engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finish')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

    current_scene.enter()
```

Comment: `current_scene` is only defined within the `play()` method, and the `current_scene.enter()` line is not a part of that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be an indentation error. The last `current_scene.enter()` should probably be indented to be inside of `def play(self):`, and lined up with `current_scene = ...`.

Comment: Not all hereos wear capes, thanks man, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I'm here to help. It's an easy thing to miss in Python (and other languages), and having answers that highlight this is one of the best resources.